# How can I view a [web]page's source right in terminal?

Tags: command-line, browser, web, source-code

I've heard of lynx and links and other text-based browsers and those are fine, but I want get to the same information I'd see by executing `View Page Source` in Firefox for example. (IE and Chrome have their own similar functionality.)

Is it possible to view this source via Terminal (or CLI) by browsing to the page in a terminal based application, or using commands? This isn't as simple as using `wget` on a page, as that won't fill scripted info (.cgi, .php, .js, etc.).

Comment: I have seen curl - how does this answer the question?

Comment: It's not an "_answer_" per-se... As I said, you _cannot_ get the original source for PHP files and the like from a correctly configured server... Even the `view-source:` prefix won't do that...

Comment: Use `wget` with the `-O -` option.  What @Attie says about grabbing server side source is correct - you will only see what the browser is sent.  in the case of pages build with javascript, you MIGHT be able to see the js, or at least references to it with the URLs to again download and get it.

Answer (score 3):

Many CLI/TUI browsers have source-viewing capability built in. In Lynx or Links, the keybinding for viewing source is <kbd>\</kbd>. In w3m it is <kbd>v</kbd>. For other browsers see the relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There are likely two easy ways to get what you want (the text returned by e.g. `view-source:`):

- *wget*

  Besides Linux, [wget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) is available on Windows with the [GnuWin32 wget package](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm). More up-to-date versions are also available from [Eternally Bored](https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/) as well, not to mention simply by using [WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) in Windows 10.
- *Python*

  [Python](https://www.python.org/) with the third-party [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module (which both work on Linux and Windows).

Assuming Python is installed, you can get Requests by using `pip` (with something like `python -m pip install requests`) or you can visit the [Requests PyPi page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests).

Note that in either case, you should take a moment to pick a suitable [User-Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) string. You can Google ["What is my user agent string?"](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+my+user+agent+string) in any browser you wish to emulate to see the current User-Agent string associated with your GUI browser.

---

*Another potential option is to use Python with [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/). Selenium is technically used for browser automation but, keeping with the command line requirements, you can use it with any browser that supports "headless" (non-GUI) mode. This includes current versions of Chrome and Firefox.*

*The Python version of Selenium is available on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) and you can install it with e.g. `python -m pip install selenium`. For a browser, I might recommend the [UnGoogled Chromium builds from Woolyss](https://chromium.woolyss.com/), since they are light(er)weight and have an appropriate version of `chromedriver` bundled with them.*

---

**wget**

As suggested by @Attie and @ivanivan, `wget` can retreive the same source as displayed by a GUI browser with *ex.*:

```
wget -O pagesource.html -U "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0" --no-check-certificate https://www.google.com
```

In the example above, `-O` (the output file option) and `-U` (the User-Agent string option) are the key to (generally) retrieving the same format as you might have in, say, Firefox. This method does have the small drawback that you will need to display *ex. pagesource.html* on the command line yourself.

---

**Python**

Your other option is to use Python with Requests, as already mentioned.

To get the actual page source as seen (generally) with e.g. `view-source:`, create a script similar to the following:

```
import requests

user_agent = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0'}
url = 'https://www.google.com'

response = requests.get(url, headers=user_agent)

print(response.text)
```

You save this script as something like *pagesource.py*, then call it from the command line *ex.*:

```
python pagesource.py | more
```

`more` simply prevents the entire page from being dumped at once. It's worth mentioning that response objects have a `content` attribute (which is very similar to `text` for our purposes) but `text` in this case more closely emulates what is returned by a GUI browser when viewing a page's source code.

---

*If using Selenium, one option for accessing a web page's source code is using the `page_source` attribute of your remote driver object after using `get()`.*

---

**Page Rendering**

> This isn't as simple as using `wget` on a page, as that won't fill scripted info (`.cgi`, `.php`, `.js`, etc.).

Pages rendered via server-side scripting (`.cgi`/`.php` in your question) have their source code generated as text (i.e. `.html` and JavaScript) *before* being handed over to the browser.

With JavaScript, the browser processes any JavaScript into a final rendered page itself (there is no "intermediate" form). The browser can actually alter the page code in these cases (i.e. it may modify what you see in `view-source:`). Similarly, the browser takes extra steps to follow links and download necessary resources (e.g. `.css`, media files, etc.) for final display.

What this means is that what you see in the browser's "page source" is (generally speaking) exactly what the browser uses to initially render the page. If an `.html` link to an item (say a picture or video) doesn't exist, it doesn't exist (though this doesn't necessarily preclude any JavaScript code from being informative).

That said, you may wish to take note of and experiment with different User-Agent strings. Servers that dynamically generate content often do so based on these strings. Therefore, it's at least theoretically possible a page may generate more traditional resource links vs. JavaScript code based on, for example, a mobile browser vs. a desktop browser string.

Comment: Does not get page source the same way the "View Page Source" button does. For example with a Steam store page. By using that button you can see the tags, but by using the script, you can't. I'm using my browser's UA string, and I've tried other strings.

Comment: The methods described above can give the same output as `view-source`. However, they aren't immune to "outside" influence. Sites can tailor their responses before the page is even returned or browsers may may "modify" the page source themselves.

Comment: *"For example with a Steam store page. By using that button you can see the tags, but by using the script, you can't."* - While it is true that Steam seems to be hard to replicate exactly, both methods described above will retrieve (at least) user-defined tags, general tags (e.g. Genre, Developer, etc.) and game pricing information from individual game pages (e.g. `https://store.steampowered.com/app/123456/Game_Blah_Blah/`). They both will also retrieve similar data from the main `https://store.steampowered.com/` page. If you are having issues, you should probably clarify what those are.

Comment: The elements of the div class "glance_tags" do not appear using these methods. I had to use Selenium to get them. So now I'm working with that.

Comment: Hmm. I couldn't replicate that issue. But yes, Selenium is the next step up. Glad you got things working.